# Removing rows from dataframe that occurs in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with removing rows from dataframe that occurs in another dataframe.
Below simple example and expected results.

df1

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Z | 1 |
| X | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| V | 4 |

df2

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| DD | 66 |
| Z | 1 |
| X | 2 |
| CC | 55 |

Expected output, df2 but rows that occur in df1 are dropped.

new df2:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| DD | 66 |
| CC | 55 |

Edit: I need to match both A and B.

Comment: do you want to match on both A and B to remove?

Comment: @mozway yes,  I need to match both A and B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a reverse [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with help of `indicator=True`:

```
(df2
 .merge(df1, how='left', indicator=True) # if unrelated columns use on=['A', 'B']
 .loc[lambda d: d.pop('_merge').eq('left_only')]
)
```

output:

```
    A   B
0  DD  66
3  CC  55
```

Answer (score 0):

use pandasql:

```
df2.sql("select * from self where not exists (select 1 from df1 where df1.A=self.A and df1.B=self.B)",df1=df1)
```

output:

```
    A   B
0  DD  66
3  CC  55
```